# authentication query in two table?

Tags: php, mysql

my website has separate tables for users and admin

now i want to give the privilege to access admin area to some users

my problem is with admin and users table

i dont know if i should copy authentication data from user table to the admin table so they can login in to the admin are  ,  or perform a query to search both tables for username and password  and just use level column to verify their access?

something like this ?

```
$sql = "select `password` , `level` from `admin` where `username` = '$username' UNION
(SELECT `password` , `level` FROM `users` where `username` = '$username') LIMIT 1 ";
$result = $db->query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
if($password == $row['passwor'] && $row['level'] != 0)
echo 'welcom to admin area';
else
echo 'login faild';
}
```

Comment: You have errors in your code. You first use select `pasword` and then $row['passwor']. Be careful.

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't simply use a field in your users table to specify if a user has admin privileges?

Comment: You should never store a password in the clear in a database. Use salted hashes for that. This is esp. important because it's a well known fact that people reuse passwords, so leaking data like that will expose much more than just the data on **this** site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you are storing passwords in the clear in your database.
This is a major security risk and should never be done.
Passwords should always be stored as salted hashes using a secure hash function.
I also fail to see the use for separate tables for admins and non-admins.

I recommend you alter your table layout.

```
table user
-------------
id unsigned integer auto_increment primary key,
username varchar(100) not null,
salt varchar(20) not null,
passhash varchar(48) not null,
isadmin boolean not null default false
```

Query your table with:

```
SELECT u.id, u.isadmin FROM user u
WHERE u.username = '$username' 
  AND passhash = SHA2(CONCAT(u.salt, '$password'),512)
  AND isadmin = 1
```

When creating a user use:

```
INSERT INTO user (username, salt, passhash, isadmin) 
   VALUES ('$username', '$salt', SHA2(CONCAT('$salt','$password'),512), '$isadmin')
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use LEFT JOIN and no need for a loop :

```
    $sql = 'SELECT `a`.`password`, `a`.`level` FROM `admin` AS `a` LEFT JOIN `users` ON `a`.`username` = `u`.`username` WHERE `a`.`username` = "'.$username.'" LIMIT 1';
    $result = $db->query($sql);
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

    if($password == $row['passwor'] && $row['level'] != 0)
        echo 'welcom to admin area';
    else
        echo 'login faild';
```

But you should create a field in your users table and use an int to give rights like :
0 is a user, 1 is a super user, 2 moderator and 3 admin... this is an example. Then you use DEFINE in PHP to setup your class. Also, encode your password. I recommend SHA-512.